# Does the One-Handed Style talent bonus still work with a shield equipped?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

Similar to the question [Does the Larder Door work with the Two Weapon Style talent?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211746/does-the-larder-door-work-with-the-two-weapon-style-talent), I was wondering if the One-Handed Style talent bonus still applies when you have a shield equipped in the other hand?

The text of [One-Handed Style](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/One-Handed_Style) reads:

> While wielding a single one-handed melee weapon, 20% of the attacker's Grazes are converted to Hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is a seperate One Hand + Shield style which provides a bonus to defense.

Comment: It would have been nice if the in-game description was clearer in that regard, because if I equip a sword in one hand and a shield in the other, technically I'm still wielding a one-handed melee weapon :P

Answer (score 9):

Yes, one-handed style and weapon and shield style stack together, as demonstrated by a graze being converted to a hit in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot of proof]

Comment: Hi Aggnog! Thanks for doing the research on this. I've edited your post to better fit our format. Feel free to [edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/214407/edit) it further if I've missed anything. I hope to see you around :D